# how to use like query in drupal

Tags: sql, drupal, drupal-6

How to write  SQL LIKE Query in drupal ,

```
SELECT title FROM { node } WHERE type='%s'
```

i want to add the LIKE CONDITION IN THAT

```
SELECT title FROM { node } WHERE type='%s' AND LIKE '%S%'
```

i think i writtern wrong like query formnat, can rewrite and tell me,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use % to escape.

```
$result = db_query('SELECT title FROM {node} WHERE type = "%s" AND title LIKE "%%%s%%"', 'type', 'title');

while ($row = db_fetch_object($result)) {
     // do stuff with the data
}
```

Node type does not need escaping.

Answer (score 5):

And here is an example with how to use LIKE in a dynamic query (**Drupal 7 Only**):

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
        ->fields('n', array('title'))
        ->condition('type', 'my_type')
        ->condition('title', '%' . db_like(search_string) . '%', 'LIKE');
    $result = $query->execute()->fetchCol();
```

[`db_like()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_like/7) is used to escapes characters that work as wildcard characters in a LIKE pattern.

Comment: This is wrong, the question was asked about Drupal 6. You provided a Drupal 7 answer

Comment: Good point - I edited my answer to made it clear that this only works on Drupal 7. Could still prove useful to someone...

Comment: @FelixEve indeed it has helped me with D7. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

drupal_query replace %% to % and %s to value string

so your code will be

```
$sql = "SELECT title FROM node WHERE type='%%%s' AND title LIKE '%%%S%%'";
$type = "type to use in query";
$title = "title to use in query";    
$result = db_result(db_query($sql, $type, $title));
```

Answer (score 3):

OK, so you want the `LIKE` operator to refer to the `title` column. Use this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT title FROM node WHERE type='%s' AND title LIKE '%S%'";
$type = "type to use in query";
$title = "title to use in query";    
$result = db_result(db_query($sql, $type, $title));
```

This is because the `LIKE` operator requires a column name to be specified. Otherwise, your database doesn't have any idea what value you want to perform the comparison on. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp).

Comment: i want like operator for title field

Comment: This is correct, but you have to add variables to substitute for those placeholders. So,

$sql = db_query("SELECT title FROM node WHERE type='%s' AND title LIKE '%S%'", $type, $title);
$result = db_result($sql);

where $type and $title are equal to the things you're filtering for. You may have known this; I just wanted to state the obvious.

Comment: Ah! As noted in the answer below, you have to escape the %s. so %S% should be %%%S%%.